# One liner if in nodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am defining the following variable:

```
var locationObj = {
    latitude: result.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: result.geometry.location.lng,
    streetNumber: _.find(addComp, function (comp){return comp.types.indexOf('street_number') > -1}).long_name || '',
    route: _.find(addComp, function (comp){return comp.types.indexOf('route') > -1}).long_name || '',
    htmlAddress: result.adr_address,
    address: result.formatted_address,
    vicinity: result.vicinity,
    modifiedAt: Date.now()
}
```

the problem is, the `comp` object may be null and i want to write a one liner if within the var object to set the property value as empty if `comp` is null. how should i do this?

Comment: Can you show only the parts relevant to the question?

Comment: Ternary operators are one-liner ifs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this:

```
return  comp ? comp.types.indexOf('route') > -1 : false;
```

this will return `false` if comp is `null` or `undefined`